# What's a good control for allowing a user to define colours for numeric ranges?

Tags: sliders, range

I've created a multi-value slider that allows the user to set colours to be used for a range of values from 0 to 100. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

The user can slide each number left and right to change it, except for 0 which is always anchored at the left-hand side.

To add a new value, the user clicks on an empty space on the slider, and a value appears. To remove a value the user drags it off the slider.

To change the colour, the user clicks and releases on a number. This opens a colour panel with a preset colour range, and a "more" triangle for a full colour chooser:

[image]

This control has been in our desktop software for some years, and seems to be used without problems.

**Now the problem**: we want to add sliders for values that do not have a clear upper limit and are not integers. How can I modify this concept to allow entering in amounts with no preset range? Or is there a straight-forward alternative?

Comment: How important is it they pick their own as opposed to having several options to choose from?

Comment: @whatsisname very important - some of the users are very demanding over the level of customisation.

Comment: By "not integers" do you mean decimals (eg 3.1415) or more abstract scalar values like (small, medium, large)?

Comment: @tohster i mean decimals, with typically no more than one decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

My suggestion is using tooltips where people can enter the value themselves.